# Why are my "other" flags not getting reviewed?

Tags: support, flags

I have three pending "other" flags from February 26<sup>th</sup> (week ago) that have not yet been reviewed. Is this because of anything I have done, or are the new mods already backed up?

Comment: There are 2k+ flags in the queue and 1.4k+ are other flags that take time to review.  Other flags can only be reviewed by moderators.

Comment: "Other" Flags can be reviewed by diamond moderators **only**. They take a longer time to get reviewed.

Comment: If it's something urgent (e.g. sock puppet report, spam or offensive post still in the open) you can bring it here on Meta.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian oh yeah, this too. ;)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian This is specifically about "other" flags that require a diamond mod's review. (Flag weight is still dead, right?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Other" flags require time for the ♦ moderators to read them and judge what they need to do with them. Most of these flags are not cookie-cuter cases and require more than a couple minutes to read into them, assess the situation, and resolve them.

Considering there are a limited number of ♦ moderators (who are the only ones who can address these flags) and the fact that there are likely a few thousand of them at any given time, I would assume that is why you haven't seen any action taken on them yet. It's only been a week. Patience, my friend!